# Need help with a grade $10$ math problem

Tags: trigonometry

A communications tower is supported by guy wires. One guy wire is anchored at a point that is $8.9$ $m$ from the base of the tower and has an angle of inclination of $36°$. From this point, the angle of elevation of the top of the tower is $59°$. How far from the top of the  tower is the guy wire attached to the tower$?$ please explain.

In my opinion the guy wire anchor is above the level of the base of the tower by 36°. so if Top of the tower is T, Base of the tower is B and anchor is A, drawing a horizontal from A to the tower and call it Z gives you a right triangel BZA with BA at 8.9 m therefore AZ = COS 36°(8.9) and therefore AZ=7.2 m. AT which is the distance of top of the tower to the anchor is 7.2/ COS 59°= 13.9 m but the answer sheet in the back of the book says 8.3 m –

Comment: What are your own ideas, approaches etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. homework problems without effort are generally discouraged and could get down voted quickly

Comment: @math12, in my opinion the guy wire anchor is above the level of the base of the tower by 36°. so if Top of the tower is T, Base of the tower is B and anchor is A, drawing a horizontal from A to the tower and call it Z gives you a right triangel BZA with BA at 8.9 m therefore AZ = COS 36°(8.9) and therefore AZ=7.2 m. AT which is the distance I'd top of the tower to the anchor is 7.2/ COS 59°= 13.9 m but the answer sheet in the back of the book says 8.3 m

Comment: @MehdiHeidari Please, add additions directly to the body of your question next time.

Comment: @Masi, I will. thank you.

Comment: I think the guy wire anchor is on the ground, at the same level as the base of the tower.

Comment: @Arentino, Then what does 36° angel of inclination from the anchor to the base of the tower mentioned in the begining means?

Comment: Open said grade 10 math book and check how $\cos$ and especially $\tan$ work in a right triangle!

Comment: @Christoph, thank you very much for your advice. Tan= opposite/adjacent and and cos=adjacent/hypotenuse. I think the issue I have is to put all the info into a picture.

Comment: Were you to split *"One guy wire is anchored at a point that is 8.9 m from the base of the tower and has an angle of inclination of 36°."*, it would read:

*"One guy wire is anchored at a point that is $8.9$ m from the base of the tower. This same guy wire has an angle of elevation of $36^{\circ}$"*

Always be careful of grammar. It can throw you off sometimes.

Comment: @John Joe, thank you very much for explaining it to me. yes the guy wire is on a level ground with angel of inclination of 36° connected to the tower at point Z 8.9 m from the base. and the line of sight to the top of the tower is 59°.

Answer (score 1):

Top of the tower: T, Base of the tower: B, Connection of anchor to the tower: Z, Anchor A. TZ=TB-BZ => Tan 36°(8.9)=BZ= 6.4662 m and Tan 59°(8.9)=TB= 14.8120 => TZ= 8.3 m